# Jenkins Groovy script fails after upgrade to version 2.361.2 from 2.346.2

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Jenkins is running on a Windows 2016 server and has both Ubuntu 20.0 and Windows Server 2019 nodes. All instances are using Java 11. Following the Jenkins upgrade to 2.361.2 from 2.346.2 the following Groovy script fails on the Ubuntu node but continues to run on the Windows node (the Windows script uses the backslash with the filename).

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.util.*

def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
def workspace = build.getWorkspace()
println workspace

def channel = null
if (workspace.isRemote())
{
    channel = workspace.channel
}
println channel

fp = new hudson.FilePath(channel, build.workspace.toString() + "/Version.h")
println fp

contents = ""
if (fp != null) {
    contents = fp.readToString()
}
```

The output is:

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/Build
hudson.remoting.Channel@5c9b8918:Dizzy-Linux

/home/jenkins/workspace/Version.h
FATAL: Input length = 1
Also: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to Dizzy-Linux
at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1784)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1000)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1186)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1175)
at hudson.FilePath.readToString(FilePath.java:2369)
at hudson.FilePath$readToString$1.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
```

The file /home/jenkins/workspace/Version.h does exist.
I tried updating the Groovy plugin but the problem persists.